# The cutout corner box problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An open-top box is created by cutting squares out of corners of an 8.5-inch by 11-inch sheet of paper and then folding up the sides.

[image: sheet of paper with square corner cut-outs]

[Click image to enlarge]

They ask me to define a function $f$ to determine the volume of the box (measured in cubic inches) in terms of the length $x$ of the side of the square cutout (in inches), and I am not really sure what they are asking me to do here.

Comment: Start by drawing a diagram and looking at it.

Comment: I added an image, to illustrate what the problem is about.  It is fairly straightforward to come up with the formula for $f$, the volume of the open-top box.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the volume, $f:length⋅width⋅heigth$.

Since you are cutting out squares you only need one variable, $x$. Your lengt will be $8,5-x-x $ since you are cutting out squares at both ends. Your width $11-x-x$. And the heigth $x$ since you are folding the squares up.

So your function $f$ of your volume will be $f(x)=(8,5-2x)⋅(11-2x)⋅x$

=$f(x)=4x^3-39x^2+93,5x$

only don't forget to convert the inches to cm

Comment: Why the nonsense about centimetres? It could be cubits or furlongs, the maths is the same. Are you just trying to confuse the OP?

Comment: in his discription he said he wanted the volume in cubic centimeters, and he gave the discription of the sheet of paper in inches so you need to convert them right?

Comment: I've looked through the edit history and I can't see anything about centimetres.